# Getting user's first and last name in Liferay 6.2 velocity template

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-6, velocity

I'm trying to display something like:

> Welcome John Doe

In my Liferay Velocity Based Template which is used in a `WebContent` on Liferay 6.2 GA1 CE

So far the code i have is the following:

```
#set ($userLS = $portal.getClass().forName('com.liferay.portal.service.UserLocalServiceUtil'))
#set ($userId = $getterUtil.getLong($request.get("theme-display").get("user-id")))
#set ($user = $userLS.getUserById($userId))

<div class="user-welcome">
    #if($user.isMale())
        <span class="welcome-msg">Bienvenido</span><br>
    #else
        <span class="welcome-msg">Bienvenida</span><br>
    #end
    <span class="username">$user.getFullName() $user.getLastName()</span>
</div>
```

The errors i'm having are:

1. `$user.isMale()` always returns false
2. in my `span.username` the output is the code itself. It doesn't print the value.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Edit: The answer to your question upfront, I'll leave the rest of the explanation below:

If you want to access the current user, you can get it from $permissionChecker. So just replace your first three lines with this:

```
 #set( $user = $permissionChecker.getUser() )
```

---

Here's my old explanation on why the technique used in your question didn't work:

Check `$userLS.getClass().getName()`: It's already not resolving properly. The reason most likely is this setting:

```
#
# Set a comma delimited list of Java classes the Velocity engine cannot have
# access to.
#
velocity.engine.restricted.classes=\
    java.lang.Class,\
    java.lang.ClassLoader,\
    java.lang.Thread
```

[Check this Wiki article](https://www.liferay.com/de/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Access+to+Liferay+services+in+Velocity) to learn about serviceLocator, but be aware that it is - for good reasons - also unavailable from templates.

```
#
# Set a comma delimited list of variables the Velocity engine cannot
# have access to. This will affect Dynamic Data List templates, Journal
# templates, and Portlet Display templates.
#
velocity.engine.restricted.variables=serviceLocator
```

If you're the only one writing templates (or if you trust everyone doing so) it's fine to change this configuration in portal-ext.properties: Configure serviceLocator to not be restricted, then call

```
#set($userLocalService = $serviceLocator.findExceptionSafeService(
    "com.liferay.portal.service.UserLocalService"))
```

On the positive side: This will ease error handling, as the exceptionSafeService will transparently ignore all exceptions - velocity can't handle them and without this behaviour you'd see no result (and no hint for the error message) at all, should an exception occur ever.

Comment: Thank you very much, i have already created a custom portlet to display the user´s name. I´ll leave the answer here in case anyone find´s it helpful.